# How do I connect a docker container to tor proxy on local machine?

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, tor

I want to ping a website from inside my docker container through tor proxy on my local machine. Without setting the proxy, I could not be able to ping. When I run my container with:
`sudo docker run --rm -it -p9150:9150 my-container`
I got the following error:
`Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9150: bind: address already in use.`
I started tor-browser on my localhost:9150 but I can't do port-forwarding when running a container. Also I don't want to use `--net=host` in command. I added the following line
`Environment="ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:9150"` to `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`  but it didn't word. Anyone can help me with this? (OS: Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## To run the TOR proxy and the app

After a long research I did, I came up to the following steps:

1. sudo docker pull dperson/torproxy
2. sudo docker network create tor
3. sudo docker run --rm -it --name mytor --network tor -p9050:9050 dperson/torproxy
4. sudo docker run --rm -it --network tor myapp

Inside myapp I have a python script which sends message to my telegram channel through tor socks proxy. I have a network (tor) and both containers see each other through it. In the python script I have the following line:

```
bot = telegram.Bot(token=token, request=Request(con_pool_size=10, connect_timeout=40, proxy_url='socks5h://mytor:9050'))
```

## To manually test the TOR proxy

Run another container, a general-purpose one like for example

```
docker run --rm -it --network tor ubuntu:22.04
```

Install `curl` the usual way (for example with `apt-get`in debian/ubuntu).

Then inside the command line do:

```
curl -x socks5://mytor:9050 http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
```

You'll see the IP of the TOR exit node:

[image: IP of the TOR exit node]

Comment: Awesome solution. To test I'd add a simple way using curl. Will edit your answer with your permission.